# How to study salesforce certification?

Tags: apex

i am doing last year of enggenieering.
Is it good for me to do salesforce certification ?

Comment: Not if you can't spell the course you're doing :)

Answer (score 1):

Just go on the this link "http://certification.salesforce.com/developers".

and note down the points or syllabus for exam or you can see below blog for more info.

Also have a look on "http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2011/05/salesforce-certification-401.html"

and just create a new account on salesforce developer, and also create a new  recurment app.

and register yourself on this site for exam "https://www.webassessor.com"

Answer (score 0):

About process and questions look on [krishhari.wordpress.com](http://krishhari.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/getting-salesforce-com-certified-force-com-developer-certification/)

Comment: It woud be nice if you could post a bit more words here and not just a link to some blog.

Answer (score 0):

You also can find some materials here http://developer.force.com/, you can join and test the platform so you can decide if it's worth it

Answer (score 0):

I think that having a certification will be edge over other candidates .Go for ADM 201 and Developer certifications and that will be real boost in finding a job .salesforce is one of the leading cloud technology and job opportunities are plenty.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow the salesforce forums as well as Salesforce idea forum to learn about salesforce concepts.

http://boards.developerforce.com/

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch

Thanks,
Subhani,
Salesforce Certified Developer,
www.mydbsync.com.